# Dafny: how to use both quantifiers together

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to use Dafny to verify some very simple code. The fist block is the normal version. And I just can't find a way to set a postcondition to be

"exists i forall j ~~~~~~"

I dont know how to use 2 quantifier together in Dafny, plz help. Thanks.

```
//this is a c++ version of the code
for (int lastNot0 = 0, cur = 0; cur < nums.length; cur++) {
    if (nums[cur] != 0) {
        swap(nums[lastNot0 ++], nums[cur]);
    }
}

//Dafny code
method moveZero(a: array<int>)
  requires a != null && a.Length > 0;
  modifies a;
  ensures exists i :: forall j :: 0 <= j < i < a.Length && a[j] != 0;
//  ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length && k != i && k != j ==> a[k] == old(a[k]);
{
  var lastNot0 := 0;
  var cur := 0;
  while(cur < a.Length)
  invariant 0 <= lastNot0 <= cur < a.Length
  {
    if(a[cur] != 0){
      swap(a, lastNot0, cur);
      lastNot0 := lastNot0 + 1;
    }
    cur := cur + 1;

  }
}

method swap(a: array<int>, i: int, j: int)
  requires a != null && 0 <= i < j < a.Length;
  modifies a;
  ensures a[i] == old(a[j]);
  ensures a[j] == old(a[i]);
  ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length && k != i && k != j ==> a[k] == old(a[k]);
{
  var temp := a[i];
  a[i] := a[j];
  a[j] := temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what kind of postcondition you are trying to add? From what I understand, you are trying to say that there exist an ```i``` for all ```j``` such that ```j<i``` and ```a[i]==0```. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I try something like 'ensures exists i :: forall j :: 0 <= j < i < a.Length && a[j] != 0;' but i doesnt work :' /!\ No terms found to trigger on.'

Comment: Ok, so first of all, in my opinion, that predicate won't work because it is possible that the array ```a``` doesn't have any member with value 0. In that case the predicate won't hold.

Comment: My question here is how to put 2 quantifier, what should I put between 'exists i' and 'forall j'. Should I use '(' or  ','  or  ':'  or '::' or what.  I think it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. The problem us there is no condition involving `i` in the quantifier. It just says that `i > j` but is doesn't relate that to the values of the array `a`. So you need to add another condition like `a[i] == 0` to the quantifier.

```
ensures exists i :: forall j :: 0 <= j < i < a.Length && a[j] != 0 && a[i] == 0;
```

This won't give you the warning about no terms found to trigger on.

Comment: but what if I don't know anything about i, since i could be a.Length and a[i] won't even exist

Comment: Also, i met another problem. is there a way I can use a method in a postcondition. For example, I have a method ```count(seq a)```, that counts the zeros in a, and in a post conditions, ```ensures count(a) < 5```. I want the postcondition to be there will be less then 5 zeros in ```a```. But dafny would not allow me to use metho. I got this error msg ```method call is not allowed to be used in an expression context (count)```

Comment: For that to be true there must exits an integer `i` such that every integer is less than `i`. So the postcondition is unsatisfiable.  At least that's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is

```
ensures exists i | 0 <= i <= a.length ::
            forall j | 0 <= j < i ::  a[j] != 0 ;
```

But then, this is trivially true (consider i==0), so maybe that's not what you mean.

From your code, you are moving all the nonzeros to the front. So you also need that the items at i and beyond are 0, so

```
ensures exists i | 0 <= i <= a.length ::
               (forall j | 0 <= j < i ::  a[j] != 0)
            && (forall j | i <= j < a.length ::  a[j] == 0);
```

or more concisely

```
ensures exists i | 0 <= i <= a.length ::
            forall j | 0 <= j < a.length ::  a[j] != 0 <==> j < i ;
```